# Metallic character of bonds?

Tags: bond, metal, ionic-compounds, covalent-compounds

Why in discussions of percent character of bonds, are only ionic and covalent bondings discussed? Do bonds not have a partial metallic character, and are either metallic and ionic-covalent?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/which-has-more-metallic-character-aluminium-or-magnesium Metallicity can be viewed as very strong delocalisation, so it's relevant only for very big molecules/networks/phases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One could think of the [Fermi surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_surface) and [conduction bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valence_and_conduction_bands) as an expression of the degree of metallic bonding, where metals such as aluminum or silver have overlapping empty and filled bands, allowing for electrical conduction, while [semiconductors have a small gap between filled and conduction bands](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-chemistry/chapter/band-theory-of-electrical-conductivity/), offering more resistance.

As @Mithoron states, metallic bonding is a bulk property. Metals behave differently as nanoparticles -- for example, bulk silver is reflective, but nanometer particles of it are black, as in photographs.